# What to do when the same ID is present in multiple rows but should be merged into one?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have tried many stackoverflow solutions, but no luck.

I have a table called `driver_zones` and there are multiple `zone_id` with same value but different `driver_id` so I want to merge `zone_id` with same value and want to attach all the `driver_id` of it.

I want query in laravel.

Below is my table (first and second `zone_id` has same value):

| driver_id | zone_id |
| --- | --- |
| sJUfNMZ2nJ | 6b3ecb1b-c29d-45b2-88b3-dabf5c8b6b62 |
| rz8lpiagH1 | 6b3ecb1b-c29d-45b2-88b3-dabf5c8b6b62 |
| qY8ynd7tX5 | 5aec1540-b62c-43e3-9182-23a89da610d1 |

And the result I want is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [zone_id] => 6b3ecb1b-c29d-45b2-88b3-dabf5c8b6b62
            [drivers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [uuid] => sJUfNMZ2nJ
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [uuid] => rz8lpiagH1
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [zone_id] => 5aec1540-b62c-43e3-9182-23a89da610d1
            [drivers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [uuid] => qY8ynd7tX5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `groupBy()`

```
> $c = collect([['driver'=>'sJUfNMZ2nJ', 'zone'=>'6b3ecb1b-c29d-45b2-88b3-dabf5c8b6b62'],['driver'=>'rz8lpiagH1', 'zone'
=>'6b3ecb1b-c29d-45b2-88b3-dabf5c8b6b62'],['driver'=>'qY8ynd7tX5', 'zone'=>'5aec1540-b62c-43e3-9182-23a89da610d1']])
= Illuminate\Support\Collection {#8586
    all: [
      [
        "driver" => "sJUfNMZ2nJ",
        "zone" => "6b3ecb1b-c29d-45b2-88b3-dabf5c8b6b62",
      ],
      [
        "driver" => "rz8lpiagH1",
        "zone" => "6b3ecb1b-c29d-45b2-88b3-dabf5c8b6b62",
      ],
      [
        "driver" => "qY8ynd7tX5",
        "zone" => "5aec1540-b62c-43e3-9182-23a89da610d1",
      ],
    ],
  }


> $c->groupBy('zone')
= Illuminate\Support\Collection {#8585
    all: [
      "6b3ecb1b-c29d-45b2-88b3-dabf5c8b6b62" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#8557
        all: [
          [
            "driver" => "sJUfNMZ2nJ",
            "zone" => "6b3ecb1b-c29d-45b2-88b3-dabf5c8b6b62",
          ],
          [
            "driver" => "rz8lpiagH1",
            "zone" => "6b3ecb1b-c29d-45b2-88b3-dabf5c8b6b62",
          ],
        ],
      },
      "5aec1540-b62c-43e3-9182-23a89da610d1" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#8560
        all: [
          [
            "driver" => "qY8ynd7tX5",
            "zone" => "5aec1540-b62c-43e3-9182-23a89da610d1",
          ],
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it's worked `$driverZone = DriverZone::all(); $driverZoneG = $driverZone->groupBy('zone_id');` i used this query.